# Xamarin Form : Error on Login page when load

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a login page where I have a check if user is logged in, then navigate to other page or stay on the login page. I don't want to put this code on `App.cs` because login page will not open on 1st load of app. Now when I navigate to login page my app crash and throws the error:

> GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 0.09ms 11-16 12:31:55.111 D/Mono 
>   (15701): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 35.82ms, stw 36.83ms promoted
>   1009K major size: 531904K in use: 471305K los size: 2048K in use: 49K

Here is my code

```
public partial class Logins : ContentPage
{
    public Logins()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Setings.AccessToken))
        {
            //
            Navigation.PushAsync(new CartDetail());
        }
        else
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Logins());
        }
    }
```

Comment: try executing app in other version of android than check what happening. Where exception throwing when you debugging.

Comment: what u mean other version of android? and i have added this code in exception it doesnt throw any exception its just crash

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive navigation inside your constructor.

When the property `Setings.AccessToken` is empty you navigate to a new `Logins` page. Because you create a new `Logins` page, you also check again for the `AccessToken`. And it is still empty, so you create again a new `Logins` page and again and again and again...

Quote from your question

> [...] or stay on the login page.

To stay on the page, just don't navigate to it in the constructor. Leave the `else` part empty will show the `Logins` page.

**Hint:** It is not recommended to navigate inside a constructor, because of two reasons:

1. The navigation method `PushAsync` is asynchronous. So you can wait on it until the navigation finishes (that is not possible in the constructor)
2. You should check for navigation outside the page itself (in fact: before you create the `Logins` page first). Or: You have to load the page, and check the `AccessToken` afterwards. Why? You create a page to show it, and not to check if another one needs to be shown...